# Your hand goes in and pull it out

Tags: word-usage, grammar

Your shirt is on inside-out.

> "Your hand goes in and pull it out."
>
> "Your hand goes in and flip it out."

How do we say clearly the action to put the inside-out shirt to right position?

Comment: "turn the shirt rightside-out". If somebody doesn't know how to do that, good luck explaining it in writing.

Comment: @ThePhoton indeed.  Although I suppose you can imagine this question is aimed at instructing small children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Reach in** and **turn it** rightside-out

This is probably the most natural way explain this.  You could say "put your hand in" when instructing young children, but with adults you would use "reach in/into":

> **Reach** into the cupboard and get me a cookie, would you?

Meanwhile, you *turn* a shirt (or any similar object) inside-out, and turn it again rightside-out:

> If you want me to sew up the hole in your jacket, first **turn it inside-out** for me.

Comment: Can I say, "Put your hand in and turn it rightside-out"?

Comment: @e12345678  Yes, but as I said "put your hand in" is something you might say to young children, not adults who know the verb "to reach in".

Comment: Relevant:  [The Hokey Pokey Dance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfPg_GzC-HA), probably known to anyone who grew up (or is growing up) in the United States.